# Building a user interface for a simple discount client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, design-patterns

There are *product entity*, and several *discount decorators* in my domain.

```
// the client

[Test]
public void ChainedDiscountShouldWork() { 
    // arrange
    var product = new SimpleProduct {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        PricePerPiece = 10M,
        SelectedQuantity = 10,
        Title = "simple product"
    };

    var itemsToApplyTheDiscount = 5;
    var itemsYouGetFree = 2;
    var discountPercentage = 0.3M;

    var discountA = new BuyXGetYFreeDecorator(product, itemsToApplyTheDiscount, itemsYouGetFree);
    var discountB = new FixedDiscountDecorator(discountA, discountPercentage);

    // act
    var totalCost = discountB.CalculateCost();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(42M, totalCost);
}
```

How do I build the UI so that I can apply the (chained) discounts like it's done in my tests?

I could show a list of discount plans at stage of creation of a new product. *Signatures* of decorators constructors are *different*. Don't know how to utilize this universally.

Okay. It is possible to use `Builder` pattern. need an example.

Need an advice. How would you implement that at web UI (in my case `ASP.NET MVC`)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should take a look around Partial View concept, here is the article which will help you little bit.
http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

Keeping discounted data in App.config is fine, however that can be changed or updated so make sure user have some access around it.
In Live environment, we shouldn't be manipulating configs much so how about putting it in DB?
I would do it, putting it in DB.